# What is the time-complexity in a binary search?

Tags: python, time-complexity, big-o, binary-search

```
def binsearch(a):
    if len(a) == 1:
        return a[0]
    else:
        mid = len(a)//2
        min1 = binsearch(a[0:mid])
        min2 = binsearch(a[mid:len(a)])
        if min1 < min2:
            return min1
        else:
            return min2
```

I have tried to come up the time-complexity for min1 < min2 and I feel that it is O(n) but I am not very sure if it's correct. Could someone please try to explain to me how to calculate time-complexity for such code?

Comment: You mean specifically the line `if min1 < m2`, what is the time complexity of that one line? Or are you asking about the time complexity of the entire function?

Comment: @JohnKugelman specifically the line :(

Comment: What is `a`, a list of numbers?

Comment: @JohnKugelman a is array yes list of numbers

Comment: Hmm.  This looks like a complicated version of the `min` function.  I'm still not sure what you're question is.  How many times will the statement `min1 < min2` be executed?  You can't talk about the time complexity of a single isolated arithmetic expression.

Comment: @FrankYellin Sure you can.

Comment: @Arty It's named `binsearch`, but this is not a binary search.

Comment: @JaeYing I didn't notice that your function is not actually a binary search. Your function is `O(n)`. While `min1 < min2` as a single expression is `O(1)`.

Comment: @JohnKugelman if it's not a binary search then what it is? :O

Comment: @Arty could you explain to me why is it O(n)? :(

Comment: @JaeYing It is called binary search, but actually inside each function call it does one comparison plus processes two parts of size `n/2`, both `n` in total size. So basically it doesn't halven the size of processed array as binary search does.

Comment: @JaeYing You may think next way - in order to find minimum of whole array that your function does you need to look at all of N numbers, you can't miss any of them. So difficutly is at least `O(N)`.

Comment: @Arty Good observation that this is binary search only in name.

Comment: @ThijsvanDien I think it is called binary search, because it actually builds a binary tree, having N-1 inner nodes and N leaves. This tree computes minimum of whole array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `min1` and `min2` are numbers, and there's always 2 (a constant) of them,  the amount of work on that particular line (a single comparison) never changes. Therefore its time complexity is `O(1)`.

What may change, however, is the number of times that line is executed! When you have `n` times an `O(1)` operation, the overall time complexity is still `O(n)`.

Comment: What is the time complexity of the splicing operation?  Is it O(1) or O(n)?  Depending on that, this algorithm is either O(n) or O(n log N).

Comment: @FrankYellin This algorithm builds a binary search tree. It has N leaves. And N-1 inner nodes. Only inner nodes operations are counted, comparison of `min1 < min2`, leaves don't do comparisons. So total complexity is `O(N)`. Of cause it is somewhat amortized by recursive function calls operations. Slicing is also done inside inner nodes. So maybe precise complexity is around `O(4N)` which is simply `O(N)`.

Comment: I suppose I'm unsure what the question is.  What's the time complexity of this algorithm, or how many times is min1 < min2 called?  O(n log n) and O(n), respectively (assuming the splice operation is O(<number of elements>).

Comment: To be strict, slicing operation on a *list* builds a new list; slicing operation on an array may in fact be a lightweight view, depending on what kind of array and possibly other circumstances.

Comment: @sabik Yes if it is python list which probably is then slicing is costly, if it is a numpy array which is probably not (because whole function is not numpy oriented) then it of cause lightweight.

Comment: @Arty so it takes O(n) for comparison of min1 and min 2 because it does n-1 comparisons? O(n log n) because of the slicing of the arrays?

Comment: @JohnKugelman `log n` is coming from height of binary tree that is built by function. On each level (depth) of this binary tree we have same number of array elements in total which is N, algorithm is dominated by slicing which takes `O(N)` time for N elements of python list (if it is not a numpy array). Hence if we multiply we get `O(N log N)`.

Comment: @Arty but if we are just talking about comparison of min 1 < min 2 then it will just be O(1) ? im still unsure as there are too many inputs :(

Comment: @JaeYing Single comparison `min1 < min2` inside one call of function is `O(1)` for sure, it just compares two number in constant time. But total count of such comparisons for whole array is `N-1`, so total time of all such comparisons is `O(N)`.

Comment: @Arty for the complexity if this function is O(log n)?

Comment: @JaeYing BTW, your whole function can be replaced with just `result = min(a)` built in function call, it will be much more efficient in fact.

Comment: @JaeYing Yes, your whole function is `O(N log N)` mostly because of slicing list operation (`a[0:mid]` etc), if there was no slicing accounted then it would be `O(N)`.

Comment: [Empirical](https://repl.it/repls/MeagerBasicQueries) [testing](https://i.imgur.com/b6YzeWk.png) shows that the function is O(n).